# How to correctly create expressjs app on facebook parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm learning http://parse.com and follow onsite tutorial to create `expressjs` "parse hosting" app.

I created a deployed simple app withou problems, it's accessible via `<subdomain>.parseapp.com` and displays `public/index.html`:

```
parse new
parse deploy
```

After that I generated `expressjs` app via:

```
parse generate
```

and modified `main.js` as instructed by adding following as a first string:

```
require('cloud/app.js');
```

Unfortunately, after deploying modified app it still displays `index.html` content. Seems it's some setting like "enable expressjs" that I can't see in documentation or app settings. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the code in `index.html`? Express/Node is the server powering your app which is serving the index page. Unless you make changes to the HTML in the index page, you'll keep seeing the original generated file.

Comment: Nope, manual doesn't state anything about changing index.html, express page should be available via /hello url.

Comment: Yes, the page will be available through the `/hello` endpoint but it's rendering an HTML page or some text. In your case, I think that route is rendering `index.html` which will need to be updated. That's how the web works my friend.